# Serverless Framework With AWS, scheduling

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I have a function that runs on a schedule. The crontab looks like this:

```
  - schedule:
    rate: cron(0 0 1 ? * FRI *)
```

When I deploy the function I'm not sure what triggers it in the aws lambda. In the console I only see the API gateway

[image]

How do I know what triggers my schedule that I set in serverless?

Answer (score 2):

Just only using `rate` or `cron` not both. This mean your syntax is wrong.

A suggestion for your case

```
...
    events:
      - schedule: cron(0 0 1 ? * FRI *)
...
```

Official document [Serverless Schedule](https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/schedule/)